# Firebase deploy only showing home page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment

I have deployed a web app from React and it has successfully loaded the app home page.

However, when I click to go to any of the other pages on the site it returns a 404 with page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following, "rewrites:", to my firebase.json file solved the issue:

```
"hosting": {

    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
 "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```